# No incluir registros en Consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas, libro y prestamo, quiero listar todos los libros pero que no estén en la tabla prestamo, esta es mi consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT libro.* FROM libro, prestamo 
WHERE libro.ejemplar != prestamo.libro_ejemplar 
AND libro.ISBN != prestamo.libro_ISBN
```

Pero no me muestra menos registro,

```
     ISBN        ejemplar  nombre_libro                             categoria  n_paginas  
----------  --------  ---------------------------------------  ---------  -----------
11-213-937  2         Programacion WEB                                14          230
11-213-937  3         Programacion WEB                                14          230
11-213-937  4         Programacion WEB                                14          230
11-213-937  1         Programacion WEB                                14          230
20221506    2         PHP                                             14          300
20221506    1         PHP                                             14          300
34-000-000  10        Programacion Movil                              14          480
34-000-000  4         Programacion Movil                              14          480
34-000-000  5         Programacion Movil                              14          480
34-000-000  9         Programacion Movil                              14          480
84-369-044  9X        La polifonia clasica                            17          169
84-369-044  9XX       La polifonia clasica                            17          169
84-369-044  9         La polifonia clasica                            17          169
84-932914-  1         Salmos de visperas                               1          135
978-958-24  1         Experiencias de aprendizaje Ciencias 10         13          160
9788441544  2021G     El Libro del Hacker                             15          744
9788441544  2021F     El Libro del Hacker                             15          744
9789588461  XX        OPIO EN LAS NUBES                                8          180
```

Estos son los registros de la tabla libro

```
    ISBN        ejemplar  nombre_libro                             categoria  n_paginas  
----------  --------  ---------------------------------------  ---------  -----------
11-213-937  1         Programacion WEB                                14          230
11-213-937  2         Programacion WEB                                14          230
11-213-937  3         Programacion WEB                                14          230
11-213-937  4         Programacion WEB                                14          230
20221506    1         PHP                                             14          300
20221506    2         PHP                                             14          300
34-000-000  10        Programacion Movil                              14          480
34-000-000  4         Programacion Movil                              14          480
34-000-000  5         Programacion Movil                              14          480
34-000-000  9         Programacion Movil                              14          480
84-369-044  9         La polifonia clasica                            17          169
84-369-044  9X        La polifonia clasica                            17          169
84-369-044  9XX       La polifonia clasica                            17          169
84-932914-  1         Salmos de visperas                               1          135
978-84-939  1         El corazon de la piedra                          8          560
978-84-939  2         El corazon de la piedra                          8          560
978-84-939  3         El corazon de la piedra                          8          560
978-958-24  1         Experiencias de aprendizaje Ciencias 10         13          160
9788441544  2021F     El Libro del Hacker                             15          744
9788441544  2021G     El Libro del Hacker                             15          744
9789588461  XX        OPIO EN LAS NUBES                                8          180
```

Estos son los registros de la tabla prestamo

```
   id  libro_ISBN  libro_ejemplar  usuario_cedula  fecha       
------  ----------  --------------  --------------  ------------
    1  978-84-939  1               1001874388      2022-06-15  
    2  978-84-939  1               1063142471      2022-06-15
```

Debería mostrar todos los registros menos lo que haga coincidencia pero me muestra un registro menos, que hago mal?

---

Probé esta solución

```
SELECT *
FROM libro
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM prestamo
          WHERE libro.ejemplar = prestamo.libro_ejemplar 
          AND libro.ISBN = prestamo.libro_ISBN)
```

Comment: Tenes que hacer un NOT In por la columna que sea clave foranea de libro en prestamo... no tenes que hacer un join...

Comment: Nada, me muestra exactamente los mismos registros.

Comment: Y que le paso a esa solucion que probaste?

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución que puedes probar es:

```sql
SELECT A.* 
FROM libro A LEFT JOIN prestamo B ON A.ejemplar  = B.libro_ejemplar 
WHERE B.libro_ejemplar IS NULL
```

Acá tomas SOLO a los registros que están en la tabla `libros` y dejas de contar a aquellos registros que se encuentran también en `libro_ejemplar`. A nivel de conjuntos se vería como `A-B`.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la clave primaria de la tabla libro es ISBN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM libro
WHERE ISBN NOT IN (SELECT ISBN FROM prestamo)
```